# angularjs ui-grid: how to display all records taking more than one html page

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Im using angularjs grid: this component allaways displays only data which fits to page. Suppose I want to have all data displayed at once, even if it takes a few pages (page scrolling is needed to see all data, **but without grid scroll**).

How to do it?

I played with:

- parameter ui.grid.autoResize
- trying to overwrite default css
  setting.

No result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding a class to your **div**. I can see the grid scroll bars if I add a CSS like so. You need to change the below CSS according to your needs.

```
.grid {
   width: 580px;
   height: 500px;
}
```

And here is my **ui-grid**

```
<div>
    <div class="grid" ui-grid="assetGridData" ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-selection></div>
</div>
```

Also it will be good if you can have a fiddle for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to make it is to set

```
gridOptions.minRowsToShow = rows.length + 0.1
```

`0.1` is needed to completely remove the vertical scrollbar of the grid. If `0.1` doesn't work for you, try a higher value like `0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

`ui-grid-auto-resize` worked in my case